# Making this JS countdown handle minutes

Tags: javascript

I have a countdown script that enables me to see how much time there is left until a specific date and time in any given timezone. The script has improved alot from its original state (Much thanks to this community) but it still has some flaws.

The script is currently only able to countdown to a specific hour (Like 2015/12/12 18:00) but NOT to a specific minute (Like 2015/12/12 18:**25**).

I would like to be able to also specify any given minute of the hour (**var minute**), but I dont know how. Would greatly apreciate if anyone could help me out.

**Edit:** The timezone variable (var tz) must be taken into account.

**Edit2:** Solved the issue I got with the first answer, with this: toDate.setMinutes(minutes-(tz*60));

Full script below:

```
////////// CONFIGURE THE COUNTDOWN SCRIPT HERE //////////////////

var month = '11';     //  '*' for next month, '0' for this month or 1 through 12 for the month 
var day = '10';       //  Offset for day of month day or + day  
var hour = 14;        //  0 through 23 for the hours of the day
var tz = -5;         //  Offset for your timezone in hours from UTC
var lab = 'tzcd';    //  The id of the page entry where the timezone countdown is to show

function start() {displayTZCountDown(setTZCountDown(year,month,day,hour,tz),lab);}

    // **    The start function can be changed if required   **
window.onload = start;

////////// DO NOT EDIT PAST THIS LINE //////////////////

function setTZCountDown(year,month,day,hour,tz) 
{

// props to Luke Woodward at Stackoverflow
var now = new Date();

var countdownToYear = now.getFullYear();
var countdownToMonth = now.getMonth();
var countdownToDay = now.getDate();

if (month === '*') {
    countdownToMonth += 1;
} else if (month > 0) { 
    if (month <= now.getMonth()) {
        countdownToYear += 1;
    }
    countdownToMonth = month - 1;
}

if (day.substr(0,1) === '+')  {
    var day1 = parseInt(day.substr(1), 10);
    countdownToDay += day1;
} else {
    countdownToDay = day;
}

var toDate = new Date(countdownToYear, countdownToMonth, countdownToDay);
// props to Luke Woodward at Stackoverflow^

toDate.setHours(hour);
toDate.setMinutes(0-(tz*60));
toDate.setSeconds(0);
var fromDate = new Date();
fromDate.setMinutes(fromDate.getMinutes() + fromDate.getTimezoneOffset());
var diffDate = new Date(0);
diffDate.setMilliseconds(toDate - fromDate);
return Math.floor(diffDate.valueOf()/1000);
}
function displayTZCountDown(countdown,tzcd) 
{
if (countdown < 0) document.getElementById(tzcd).innerHTML = "<li>0<br><span class='tzcd-format'>day</span></li><li>0<br><span class='tzcd-format'>hours</span></li><li>0<br><span class='tzcd-format'>minutes</span></li><li>0<br><span class='tzcd-format'>seconds</span></li>"; 
else {var secs = countdown % 60; 
if (secs < 10) secs = '0'+secs;
var countdown1 = (countdown - secs) / 60;
var mins = countdown1 % 60; 
if (mins < 10) mins = '0'+mins;
countdown1 = (countdown1 - mins) / 60;
var hours = countdown1 % 24;
var days = (countdown1 - hours) / 24;
document.getElementById(tzcd).innerHTML = "<li>" + days + "<br><span class='tzcd-format'>day" + (days == 1 ? '' : 's') + '</span></li>' + "<li>" + hours + "<br><span class='tzcd-format'>hours</span></li> " + "<li>" + mins + "<br><span class='tzcd-format'>minutes</span></li>" +"<li>"+secs+ "<br><span class='tzcd-format'>seconds</span></li>";
setTimeout('displayTZCountDown('+(countdown-1)+',\''+tzcd+'\');',999);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to test it but this should be it:

```
////////// CONFIGURE THE COUNTDOWN SCRIPT HERE //////////////////

var month = '11';     //  '*' for next month, '0' for this month or 1 through 12 for the month 
var day = '10';       //  Offset for day of month day or + day  
var hour = 14;        //  0 through 23 for the hours of the day
var tz = -5;         //  Offset for your timezone in hours from UTC
var minutes = '10';
var lab = 'tzcd';    //  The id of the page entry where the timezone countdown is to show

function start() {displayTZCountDown(setTZCountDown(year,month,day,hour,tz),lab);}

    // **    The start function can be changed if required   **
window.onload = start;

////////// DO NOT EDIT PAST THIS LINE //////////////////

function setTZCountDown(year,month,day,hour,tz) 
{

// props to Luke Woodward at Stackoverflow
var now = new Date();

var countdownToYear = now.getFullYear();
var countdownToMonth = now.getMonth();
var countdownToDay = now.getDate();

if (month === '*') {
    countdownToMonth += 1;
} else if (month > 0) { 
    if (month <= now.getMonth()) {
        countdownToYear += 1;
    }
    countdownToMonth = month - 1;
}

if (day.substr(0,1) === '+')  {
    var day1 = parseInt(day.substr(1), 10);
    countdownToDay += day1;
} else {
    countdownToDay = day;
}

var toDate = new Date(countdownToYear, countdownToMonth, countdownToDay);
// props to Luke Woodward at Stackoverflow^

toDate.setHours(hour);
toDate.setMinutes(minutes);
toDate.setSeconds(0);
var fromDate = new Date();
fromDate.setMinutes(fromDate.getMinutes() + fromDate.getTimezoneOffset());
var diffDate = new Date(0);
diffDate.setMilliseconds(toDate - fromDate);
return Math.floor(diffDate.valueOf()/1000);
}
function displayTZCountDown(countdown,tzcd) 
{
if (countdown < 0) document.getElementById(tzcd).innerHTML = "<li>0<br><span class='tzcd-format'>day</span></li><li>0<br><span class='tzcd-format'>hours</span></li><li>0<br><span class='tzcd-format'>minutes</span></li><li>0<br><span class='tzcd-format'>seconds</span></li>"; 
else {var secs = countdown % 60; 
if (secs < 10) secs = '0'+secs;
var countdown1 = (countdown - secs) / 60;
var mins = countdown1 % 60; 
if (mins < 10) mins = '0'+mins;
countdown1 = (countdown1 - mins) / 60;
var hours = countdown1 % 24;
var days = (countdown1 - hours) / 24;
document.getElementById(tzcd).innerHTML = "<li>" + days + "<br><span class='tzcd-format'>day" + (days == 1 ? '' : 's') + '</span></li>' + "<li>" + hours + "<br><span class='tzcd-format'>hours</span></li> " + "<li>" + mins + "<br><span class='tzcd-format'>minutes</span></li>" +"<li>"+secs+ "<br><span class='tzcd-format'>seconds</span></li>";
setTimeout('displayTZCountDown('+(countdown-1)+',\''+tzcd+'\');',999);
}
}
```

Comment: Or rather, it does not take the tz variable into account?

`toDate.setMinutes(0-(tz*60));`